# Recursive function only firing once

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the following function, I don't understand why the counter function only fires once (the figure goes up by a single increment, I want it to count up to homeFigTwo).

```
function effectFour() {
  var homeFigOne = parseFloat($('.home .figure').text());
  var homeFigTwo = 23.99;
  var plusFigOne = parseFloat($('.home-plus .figure').text());
  var plusFigTwo = 28.49;
  var homeInc = homeFigOne < homeFigTwo ? .01 : -.01;
  var plusInc = plusFigOne < plusFigTwo ? .01 : -.01;

  function counterOne(){
    if (homeFigOne === homeFigTwo){
      return
    }else{
      homeFigOne = (homeFigOne + homeInc).toFixed(2);
      $('.home .figure').text(homeFigOne);
      window.setTimeout(counterOne, 100);
    }
  }
  counterOne();
}
```

This can be seen in context here: http://codepen.io/timsig/pen/NdvBKN.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: semi-colon needed after return...

Comment: @ccpgh no, it's not: automatic semicolon insertion

Comment: Are you sure the second branch of the conditional is being taken?

Comment: Hmm...what would the effect of this function be? If a certain condition is met, call counterOne with a timeout. But whether or not that condition is met (because you do not return the function after the timeout is set), call counterOne. You sure you don't want a return statement after that conditional call that invokes the counterOne-with-timeout call, so that counterOne doesn't get called every time at the bottom of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) has a Return value of

> A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.

This means that on the second time that this happens:

```
homeFigOne = (homeFigOne + homeInc).toFixed(2);
```

What's really going on is: `"16.00" = "16.00" + 0.01` which, in fact, does not possess a `toFixed` method, as that whole sentence is what.

So what you want is to `parseFloat` the result of homeFigOne again, because whenever you `toFixed` it you set it to a string again.

`homeFigOne = (parseFloat(homeFigOne) + homeInc).toFixed(2)`

Comment: That fixed it. Many thanks for your help  & for the explanation @JohannesMerz

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion is working as expected, but on your second call an error is thrown. This is because you convert `homeFigOne` to a string by using `toFixed`.

So it basically does this:

- first call: values are 15.99 23.99 (both numbers)
- second call: values are "16.00" 23.99 (a string and a number)

As the `toFixed` method is not defined for Strings an exception is thrown. As this happens async in a anonymous function, you prob. didn't noticed.

So my suggestion is to first make the increment, and only cast for your html element:

```
function effectFour() {
  var homeFigOne = parseFloat($('.home .figure').text());
  var homeFigTwo = 23.99;
  var plusFigOne = parseFloat($('.home-plus .figure').text());
  var plusFigTwo = 28.49;
  var homeInc = homeFigOne < homeFigTwo ? .01 : -.01;
  var plusInc = plusFigOne < plusFigTwo ? .01 : -.01;

  function counterOne(){
    if (homeFigOne === homeFigTwo){
      return
    }else{
      homeFigOne = homeFigOne + homeInc;
      $('.home .figure').text(homeFigOne.toFixed(2));
      window.setTimeout(counterOne, 100);
    }
  }
  counterOne();
}
```

edit:
+ as you are dealing with floats you are better of with >= instead of === for your end criterium